# ¿Cómo exportar Proyecto C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Me encontré con una duda al momento de exportar como un instalador mi proyecto de C#.

Estoy trabajando con la arquitectura de N Capas.

Aquí están mis archivos que estoy utilizando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la `CapaDatos`, tengo mi clase `Conexión`, que se conecta a mi servidor local para obtener las tablas y la información requerida.

Pero, **¿cómo exportaría la aplicación de escritorio, para así realizar un instalable y usar la base de datos SQL Server en cualquier computadora, sin tener que instalar Visual Studio y el Motor de Base de Datos?**

Comment: Puedes usar .MDF

Comment: Vea un enlace interesante: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/231074-setup-and-deployment-in-visual-studio-2010/ (Traducir del Inglés)

Comment: @JorgeLuisAlcantara 
¿Cómo sería al momento de implementar? En mi caso, ¿Tendría que cambiar código para poder conectarme a la BD?

Comment: Bueno cambiar la cadena de conexión, pasar los procedimientos almacenados, crear la bd desde visual studio.